# Two instances of application and dll it loads

Tags: c#, dll, exe, multiple-instances, static-class

I have an executable(VC++) which is run twice with different command line parameters, so basically there are two instances running. This executable loads an C# dll ,First thing i want to know is if two instances of the dll will be loaded to two different instances. If yes then I have a static class in the dll, how will this be instantiated i.e., will there be two instances of static class or will it be shared between the two process.

When i try to run the two instances of the executable, only one instance is successful in loading the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Process is loaded in its own AppDomain and nothing is shared among them even the DLLs are loaded in respective AppDomain. So there would be two separate instances of your static class in each process. Secondly, DLL is loaded in a host process. If you have Private DLL, then they are loaded separately in the process no sharing whatsoever.

The process space will be different so, for example, global variables in the DLL will be specific to each separate process. It is possible that the code in memory will be shared (Windows typically uses reference counting to make that part more efficient).